# How to get an iPhone app to appear in Spotlight with a query that doesn't exactly match

Tags: iphone, spotlight

I noticed that when I search for "Music" (for example) using Spotlight on the iPhone OS 3.0, the app "Midomi" shows up in the Spotlight results.  "Midomi" doesn't exactly match "Music", but yet it appears in the results.

How can I specify additional keywords for my app so it appears when doing a search using Spotlight, like Midomi is doing?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Midomi's full name is **Midomi Music Identifier and Search (Ultra)**. Therefore the search term 'music' will cause Spotlight to list the Midomi application. Spotlight searches both names as they appear in SpringBoard (your home screen) and their full App Store names.

(I don't know what else Spotlight searches in, but I do know it looks at these two names.)

Comment: Two years after posting this answer, my first ever on Stack Overflow, I have to note that midomi was renamed to [SoundHound](http://www.soundhound.com) as of 2010.

Comment: It appears this doesn't apply to TestFlight yet. (Tried testing it on one app only)

Answer (score 1):

It might be because Midomi has specified 'Music' as its primary or secondary category (or in the keywords) when submitting the app to store.

Comment: AppStore keywords makes sense, but does anyone know for sure that's what's going on?  It's impossible to test without submitting new keywords to the AppStore, as development builds don't have keywords.

Answer (score 0):

With the keywords now - You can also enter keywords or which you wnat your app to show up on spotlight search