# Is it possible to provide additional info about my app to the system search?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

There's a system search in iOS that allows users to search though the whole device by searching entered keyword for app names, mail messages, calendar and etc. Is it possible to provide some additional information (content info) about my app to system search? We are developing some rich-graphic-content app and there are various objects there.

The customer asked us, is it possible to implement such use case: a user enters the name of some object and system search finds that object and shows our app name in the result list :) Maybe it's possible to create some "sitemap" with information about the app content, to put that somewhere into plist and to ask  system search to use that for search index. I'm pretty sure it's impossible, just want to be 100% sure :)

**UPDATE:** One thought on that - maybe system search also uses app description text from itunes? If so then we could place additional information there and to workaround that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For static keywords (that are pre-defined when building the app), you can do this: [How to get an iPhone app to appear in Spotlight with a query that doesn't exactly match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1592375/how-to-get-an-iphone-app-to-appear-in-spotlight-with-a-query-that-doesnt-exactl)

Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any way to add keywords dynamically, e.g. for the objects/files created with your app, like the Apple-provided apps do. Hopefully, the ability to add your app's contents to Spotlight will be added in a future version of iOS (7+).

Comment: I didn't look into it, and it might be irrelevant, but there is a checkbox "Index in spotlight" for Core Data entity attributes. It might be what makes iOS index objects/files.

Comment: @FreeNickname Unfortunately, this feature is OS X only and not available on iOS.